# Multiple promise response types in React typescript, type-checking wonky

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, promise

I am using https://www.omdbapi.com/. If you need any more context I'll provide it. All the referenced functions and types are bellow my "ranty" paragraphs. Please help.

I am looking for answers to why is response data managing to enter both if statements (inside "then" callback inside `useEffect` hook). In this example I am checking if response body is a movie, if true I pass that object to my sanitizer and I do necessary clean up.

### Anomaly 1:

Once I am done typing movie title, API is called, response arrives, "then" I handle it in a callback. Inside that cb function, object manages to pass `if(isObjOfType<IOMDbError>(data))` even though it is of type `IOMDb`, and then manages to successfully set itself in state `omdbErrorMsg` *even* though I restricted that particular state to `<IOMDbError | null>`... no errors, no nothing.

### Anomaly 2:

I type in gibberish into search field on purpose, expecting

```js
{
  Error: "Movie not found!"
  Response: "False"
}
```

and I get that exact response, which is great but it also manages to pass check `if(isObjOfType<IOMDb>(data))` and tries to run `sanitizeOMDbResponse` function, and then it fails because `movie.Genre` doesn't exist and throws an error (`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')` ), which leaves me even more confused since I restricted first argument of function `sanitizeOMDbResponse` to type of `IOMDb` which response data certainly isn't.

---

I just wish to understand what am I doing wrong and what is going on.

```js
export function isObjOfType<T>(obj: unknown): obj is T {
  return !!obj;
}
```

```js
export interface IOMDb {
  Title: string;
  Year: string;
  Rated: string;
  // ... rest omitted
}
export interface IOMDbError {
  Response: string;
  Error: string;
}
export type IMovieOMdb = Pick<
  IMovie,
  'title' | 'description' | 'coverImage' | 'genres'
>;
```

```js
const [omdbMovie, setOmdbMovie] = useState<IMovieOMdb | null>(null);
const [omdbErrorMsg, setOmdbErrorMsg] = useState<IOMDbError | null>(null);
```

```js
function sanitizeOMDbResponse(
  movie: IOMDb,
  genresFromDB: IGenre[]
): IMovieOMdb | null {
  const genreLowerCase = movie.Genre.toLowerCase().split(', ');

  const newGenres = genresFromDB
    .map((genre) => {
      if (genreLowerCase.includes(genre.name)) return genre;
    })
    .filter((data) => data);

  if (isObjOfType<IGenre[]>(newGenres))
    return {
      title: movie.Title,
      description: movie.Plot,
      coverImage: movie.Poster,
      genres: newGenres,
    };

  return null;
}
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm.length !== 0) {
      searchTerm.includes(' ') &&
        setSearchTerm(() => searchTerm.replace(/ /g, '+'));

      getOMDbMovie(searchTerm).then((data) => {
        if (isObjOfType<IOMDbError>(data)) {
          setOmdbErrorMsg(data);
        }
        if (isObjOfType<IOMDb>(data) && isObjOfType<IGenre[]>(genres)) {
          const omdb = sanitizeOMDbResponse(data, genres);
          if (isObjOfType<IMovieOMdb>(omdb)) setOmdbMovie(() => omdb);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [searchTerm]);
```

Here's entire file, in case you see something weird:

```js
import useAuthGuard from 'app/hooks/useAuthGuard';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { moviesService } from 'app/services/movies.service';
import { Container, Typography, Grid, Box } from '@mui/material';
import { SearchOMDbComponent } from 'app/components/SearchOMDbComponent';
import { isObjOfType } from 'app/utils/typeCheckers';
import { IOMDb, IMovieOMdb, IOMDbError } from 'app/types/IMovies';
import { OMDbMovieDetails } from 'app/components/OMDbMovieDetails';
import useGenres from 'app/hooks/useGenres';
import { IGenre } from 'app/types/IGenre';
import { MessageComponent } from 'app/components/MessageComponent';

function sanitizeOMDbResponse(
  movie: IOMDb,
  genresFromDB: IGenre[]
): IMovieOMdb | null {
  const genreLowerCase = movie.Genre.toLowerCase().split(', ');

  const newGenres = genresFromDB
    .map((genre) => {
      if (genreLowerCase.includes(genre.name)) return genre;
    })
    .filter((data) => data);

  if (isObjOfType<IGenre[]>(newGenres))
    return {
      title: movie.Title,
      description: movie.Plot,
      coverImage: movie.Poster,
      genres: newGenres,
    };

  return null;
}

async function getOMDbMovie(movieTitle: string) {
  try {
    return await moviesService.GetOMDbMovie(movieTitle);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

export const OMDbPage = () => {
  useAuthGuard(true);
  const { getGenres } = useGenres();
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');
  const [omdbMovie, setOmdbMovie] = useState<IMovieOMdb | null>(null);
  const [omdbErrorMsg, setOmdbErrorMsg] = useState<IOMDbError | null>(null);

  const genres = getGenres();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm.length !== 0) {
      searchTerm.includes(' ') &&
        setSearchTerm(() => searchTerm.replace(/ /g, '+'));

      getOMDbMovie(searchTerm).then((data) => {
        if (isObjOfType<IOMDbError>(data)) {
          setOmdbErrorMsg(data);
        }
        if (isObjOfType<IOMDb>(data) && isObjOfType<IGenre[]>(genres)) {
          const omdb = sanitizeOMDbResponse(data, genres);
          if (isObjOfType<IMovieOMdb>(omdb)) setOmdbMovie(() => omdb);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [searchTerm]);

  console.log(omdbErrorMsg);

  return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xl">
      <Box
        sx={{
          marginTop: 8,
          marginBottom: 8,
        }}
      >
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={2}>
            <Typography variant="h3">OMDb</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={10}>
            <SearchOMDbComponent setSearchTerm={setSearchTerm} />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        {isObjOfType<IMovieOMdb>(omdbMovie) && (
          <OMDbMovieDetails omdbMovie={omdbMovie} />
        )}
        {isObjOfType<IOMDbError>(omdbErrorMsg) && !omdbErrorMsg.Response && (
          <MessageComponent message={omdbErrorMsg.Error} />
        )}
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

Comment: The two *it fails because ... doesn't exist and throws an error* and *I restricted first argument of function ... to type* are perfectly compatible. An object could be of particular type (according to the compile time type system) and the very same object can have some properties null/undefined. Just by looking at how your `isObjOfType` is implemented, my impression is that you possibly don't quite get how it works at the compile time vs how it works at the run time.

Comment: Can you please enlighten me as to *why* is that and how can I make it differentiate the two response types?

Comment: Is this implementation better? It seems fine so far:


```
export function isOMDbError(arg: unknown): arg is IOMDbError {
  return (
    !!arg &&
    typeof arg === 'object' &&
    'Response' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Response === 'string' &&
    'Error' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Error === 'string'
  );
}

```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I needed to be a lot more specific, so I wrote a lot of type-checker functions:

```js
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any */
import { IGenre } from 'app/types/IGenre';
import { IOMDb, IOMDbError, IRating, IMovieOMdb } from 'app/types/IMovies';

export function isObjOfType<T>(obj: unknown): obj is T {
  return !!obj;
}

function isGenre(arg: unknown): arg is IGenre {
  return (
    !!arg &&
    typeof arg === 'object' &&
    'id' in arg &&
    typeof arg.id === 'string' &&
    'name' in arg &&
    typeof arg.name === 'string'
  );
}

function isRating(arg: unknown): arg is IRating {
  return (
    !!arg &&
    typeof arg === 'object' &&
    'Source' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Source === 'string' &&
    'Value' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Value === 'string'
  );
}

export function isGenres(arg: any): arg is IGenre[] {
  return arg.every(isGenre);
}

function isOmdbRating(arg: any): arg is IRating[] {
  return arg.every(isRating);
}

export function isMovieOMdb(arg: unknown): arg is IMovieOMdb {
  return (
    !!arg &&
    typeof arg === 'object' &&
    'title' in arg &&
    typeof arg.title === 'string' &&
    'description' in arg &&
    arg.description === 'string' &&
    'coverImage' in arg &&
    arg.coverImage === 'string' &&
    'genres' in arg &&
    typeof arg.genres === 'object' &&
    isGenres(arg.genres)
  );
}

export function isOMDbResponse(arg: unknown): arg is IOMDb {
  return (
    !!arg &&
    typeof arg === 'object' &&
    'Title' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Title === 'string' &&
    'Year' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Year === 'string' &&
    'Rated' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Rated === 'string' &&
    'Released' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Released === 'string' &&
    'Runtime' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Runtime === 'string' &&
    'Genre' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Genre === 'string' &&
    'Director' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Director === 'string' &&
    'Writer' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Writer === 'string' &&
    'Actors' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Actors === 'string' &&
    'Plot' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Plot === 'string' &&
    'Language' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Language === 'string' &&
    'Country' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Country === 'string' &&
    'Awards' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Awards === 'string' &&
    'Poster' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Poster === 'string' &&
    'Metascore' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Metascore === 'string' &&
    'imdbRating' in arg &&
    typeof arg.imdbRating === 'string' &&
    'imdbVotes' in arg &&
    typeof arg.imdbVotes === 'string' &&
    'imdbID' in arg &&
    typeof arg.imdbID === 'string' &&
    'Type' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Type === 'string' &&
    'DVD' in arg &&
    typeof arg.DVD === 'string' &&
    'BoxOffice' in arg &&
    typeof arg.BoxOffice === 'string' &&
    'Production' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Production === 'string' &&
    'Website' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Website === 'string' &&
    'Response' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Response === 'string' &&
    'Ratings' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Ratings === 'object' &&
    isOmdbRating(arg.Ratings)
  );
}

export function isOMDbError(arg: unknown): arg is IOMDbError {
  return (
    !!arg &&
    typeof arg === 'object' &&
    'Response' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Response === 'string' &&
    'Error' in arg &&
    typeof arg.Error === 'string'
  );
}
```

Now my control flow works as intended:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (searchTerm.length !== 0) {
      setOmdbMovie(() => null);
      setOmdbErrorMsg(() => null);
      
      searchTerm.includes(' ') &&
        setSearchTerm(() => searchTerm.replace(/ /g, '+'));

      getOMDbMovie(searchTerm).then((data) => {
        if (isOMDbError(data)) setOmdbErrorMsg(() => data);
        if (isOMDbResponse(data) && isGenres(genres)) {
          const omdb = sanitizeOMDbResponse(data, genres);

          omdb && setOmdbMovie(() => omdb);
        }
      });
    }
  }, [searchTerm]);
```